# Dart Unit Test Doesn't Work

Tags: unit-testing, dart

My unit test doesn't show anything in Dartium. It is supposed to show the unit test result, but it doesn't show anything. My code is the following:

```dart
import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";
import "package:unittest/html_config.dart";
import "../../bolsaviaje/web/bolsaviaje.dart" as bolsaviaje;

void main() {
  useHtmlConfiguration();
  test("PackItem constructor", (){
    var item = new bolsaviaje.Cosa("Towel");
    expect(item,isNotNull);
  });

  test("PackItem itemtext propery",(){
    var item = new bolsaviaje.Cosa("Towel");
    expect(item.nombre,equals("Towel"));
  });
}
```

My pubspec.yaml is the following:

```dart
name: PackListTest
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  unittest: any
```

My pubspec.lock is the following:

```dart
    # Generated by pub. See: http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/glossary.html#lockfile
     {"packages":{"unittest":{"version":"0.4.1","source":"hosted","description":"unittest"},"meta":{"version":"0.4.1+1","source":"hosted","description":"meta"}}}
```

The content of my HTML file I'm using for the unit tests is the following:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PackListTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="packlisttest.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="application/dart" src="packlisttest.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The version of Dart I'm using is Dart M3.

I don't obtain anything in both: nothing in the Dartium Console and nothing in the html generated.

I have to say that I have two projects: one is the web application, and the another is my unit test Project.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of pubspec.yaml, pubspec.lock, and the version of the SDK or Editor that you are using? Thanks!

Comment: Also, can you pose the contents of the HTML file that you're using to drive the tests?

Comment: Here's a bunch of tests that work, maybe you can compare to what you're doing? https://github.com/sethladd/lawndart/tree/master/test

Comment: Do you get anything in the Dartium console and anything within the HTML?

Comment: I've updated my original post with the information that Seth Ladd and Kai Sellgren asked me. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem. I've taken two actions. The first one was to move my unit test to the same folder my app is. And the second one was to add this line to my .dart app file at the line 1:

```
library "whatever"
```

It doesn't matter what the name of the library is, because in my .dart unit test file I wrote:

```
import "bolsaviaje.dart"
```

which is the name of my app

I expect this resolution can help you if you have the same problem.

On the other hand, I don't know if there is a constraint related to having the app and the unit test in two different folders.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the following to the HTML

```
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

and add the following dependency to pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  browser: any
```

Dartium now also uses `dart.js` to bootstrap the app.

Comment: I've added what you suggested, but the result is the same, dart console and web page are in blank. May I send you my project?

Comment: The problem is this line:

import "../../bolsaviaje/web/bolsaviaje.dart" as bolsaviaje;

it seems that Dart can't resolve the path correctly, even when I specify the full path:

import "C:/Users/mercadra/Documents/Dart/BolsaViaje/web/bolsaviaje.dart";

As I said, I have two applications: one is the web application itself, and the another is my unit test project. Both are at the same level in the folder structure. I don't know if this is a constraint when using unit testing.

Comment: The Dart Editor has a built-in server that serves whatever is in the project structure.  If you are referencing a file that is outside of the project structure, then you are likely to have issues.  Quick test: in Dartium, can you browse to the file `bolsaviaje.dart`? (also, feel free to zip and send over files - use the contact details in my profile)